# Slickgrid breakpoint on filter

Tags: slickgrid

Looking at the Slickgrid examples and using Google Chrome, I'm setting a breakpoint on the filter to see what's going on internally. The breakpoint works fine on line 87 http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html

but it doesn't work on line 143

http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled Filter.

Line 197 in [Example 4](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html): `dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({ inlineFilters: true });`

When the dataView is initalized, the inlineFilters flag causes the dataView to "compile" the filter, so the original filter function isn't called. The new "compiled" function is used.

See line 201 and 466 in [slick.dataview.js](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.dataview.js) for code on Complied Filters.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the second example is setting the `inlineFilters` option of the `DataView` to true in the constructor, while the first one isn't.  What that means, is that in the second example, SlickGrid is recompiling your filter function and inlining it into the loop to avoid the function call overhead.  This significantly speeds up the filtering on large datasets.

If you want to debug it, setting a breakpoint won't work.  You need to add a `debugger` statement within the filter function itself.

Comment: The `inlineFilters: true` doesn't work for my filter but it does with `inlineFilters:false` any ideas? My code is very similar to example4

Answer (score 0):

Even though [example4](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html) sets the `myFilter` function as the dataView filter, the filtering is accomplished through the slider and textbox event wiring - check lines 288 and 303 for the same. The filter breakpoints on these should work as expected.

Comment: thanks for the response, but that's not what I'm looking for. I need the breakpoint to stop in the function that is actually deciding what is a match.

Comment: Then disable the event wiring at 288 and 303. Those functions are overriding your myFilter function. Also, why can't you find what is being matched in lines 288 through 303?

Comment: That's not it, those events are just there to setup the filter parameters that are used by `myFilter`. Anyway, I found the problem. Line 197: `dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({ inlineFilters: true });` When the dataView is initalized, the `inlineFilters` flag causes the dataView to "compile" the filter, so the original filter function isn't called. The new "compiled" function is used.